# List down all sub-Directories in Bash based on some criteria

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I'm writing a script which navigates all subdirs named something like `12`, `98`, etc., and checks that each one contains a `runs` subdir. The check is needed for subsequent operations in the script. How can I do that? I managed to write this:

```
# check that I am in a multi-grid directory, with "runs" subdirectories
for grid in ??; do
    cd $grid
    cd ..       
done
```

However, `??` also matches stuff like `LS`, which is not correct. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Next step: in each directory named `dd` (digit/digit), I need to check that there is a subdirectory named `runs`, or exit with error. Any idea on how to do that? I thought of using `find -type d -name "runs"`, but it looks recursively inside subdirs, which is wrong, and anyway if `find` doesn't find a match, I have no idea on how to catch that inside the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the directories, report the missing subdir:

```
for dir in [0-9][0-9]/ ; do
    [[ -d $dir/runs ]] || { echo $dir ; exit 1 ; }
done
```

You can use character classes in glob patterns. The `/` (not `\`) after the pattern makes it match only directories, i.e. a file named `42` will be skipped.

The next line reads "*`$dir/runs` is a directory, or report it*". `[[ ... ]]` introduces a condition, see `man bash` for details. `-d` tests whether a directory exists. `||` is "or", you can rephrase the line as

```
if [[ ! -d $dir/runs ]] ; then
    echo $dir
    exit 1
fi
```

where `!` stands for "not".

Comment: Great! Now the `for` doesn't matches `LS` anymore: +1 just for this :) what does the `\ ` after `[0-9][0-9]` do? I don't understand the following line, but instead of just reporting the missing dir, is it possible to report **and** actually exit the script? Otherwise, other parts of the script will fail spectatularly. I was thinking of something like a `case\esac` command, but I don't know how to apply it here

Comment: Wow this is great! Would +2 if it was possible :)

Answer (score 0):

First find all directories with name runs using :

```
find . -type d -name runs
```

Note: to restrict to one level you can use `find` along with `-maxdepth`

From this extract the previous directory by removing the last word after `/`

try :

```
sed 's,/*[^/]\+/*$,,'
```

Comment: Wow, you answered faster than I could edit my comment :) ok, so you suggest to use `find . -type d -name runs -maxdepth 1`. How do I catch the case that there are no matches, inside my script? Also, I don't know how to do this: "From this extract the previous directory by removing the last word after /"